# Ninject.MVC WebViewPage _Layout.cshtml Injections are Null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I am Using Ninject.MVC4 in my ASP.NET MVC4 Project and I am setting Up my Bindings in the created "NinjectWebCommon.cs" file.

I've overwritten the Default View, to Inject an Permissionmanager for my Views

```
public abstract class MvcBaseWebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    [Inject]
    public IPermissionManager PermissionManager { get; set; }
}
```

and then I've set the new BaseView in the Views web.config

```
<!--<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">-->
<pages pageBaseType="Gui.Mvc.Views.MvcBaseWebViewPage">
```

now I've access to the PermissionManager in My Views like

```
@if (PermissionManager.HasRight(RightsQsMonitor.ConfigurationTrelloVisible))
{
     <li>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <i class="fa fa-trello fa-fw"></i>&nbsp;Trello</a></li>
}
```

that works great in all Views but for the "_Layout.cshmtl" its not working here is the "PermissionManager" Instance "Null" its getting Injected too late I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a workaround is to Move the "PermissionManager" Calls into an Html.Partial - here the PermissionManager is not Null and gets Injected.

```
@Html.Partial("_MainMenue")
```